# Trouble migrating to react-router v4

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I am having trouble migrating to react router 4 with nested routes. Here was some snippets from my previous code.   was my layout container and everything was rendered within that if logged in (otherwise redirect to login)

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={ store }>
<div>
  <Router history={ history }>
    <Route path='/login' component={ Login } />
    <Route path="/password/reset" component={PasswordReset} />
    <Route path='/register' component={ Register } title={ 'Register' } />
    <Route path='/password/change/:token' component={ ChangePassword } title={ 'Register' } />
    <Route component={ EnsureLoggedInContainer }>
      <Redirect from='/' to='/dashboard' />
      <Route path='/' component={ App }>
        <Route path='/logout' component={ Logout } />
  ....
  </Router>
</div>
```

within  to render the children components:

```
class ContentLayout extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {};
}
render() {
  let children = null;
  if (this.props.children) {
    children = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
      updateHeader: this.props.updateHeader,
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className={ this.props.cls }>
      <MainHeader
        updateHeader={ this.props.updateHeader }
        header={ this.props.header }
      />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

With v4 I've been trying to figure out the proper way to render  as the layout and any child components within.  So far I've been trying to get it working but feel I am on wrong path. (Currently props.match always points to '/')

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={ store }>
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/login' component={ Login } />
          <Route exact path="/password/reset" component={PasswordReset} />
          <Route exact path='/register' component={ Register } />
          <Route exact path='/password/change/:token' component={ ChangePassword } />
          <Route path='/' component={ App } />
        </Switch>
      </div>
  </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Within App

```
const RouteWithProps = ({ component: Component, props, ...extraProps})=> {
 return (<Route
  {...extraProps} 
  render={() => <Component {...props} {...extraProps} />} 
  />
 );
}
```

and with the  component rendering

```
{securedRoutes.map((route, i) => (
    <RouteWithProps key={i} {...route} updateHeader={this.props.updateHeader} location={this.props.location} match={this.props.match} />
))}
```

What is the proper way or a good example of how to structure the app so for all logged in routes the layout is

```
<App>
  <ContentLayout>
    <Child>
```

with App passing props like updateHeader and anything else to all children.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by removing passing location and match to RouteWithProps.
I had an issue with the RouteWithSubRoutes example in dealing with nested routes for things like /.../:id and /.../:submit ended up doing this to make work so I can continue working.  Do not think this is ideal but will work till another answer on best practices.

```
const RouteWithProps = ({ component: Component, ...extraProps }) => {
  return (<Route exact path={extraProps.path}
    {...extraProps} 
    render={matchProps => <Component {...matchProps} {...extraProps} 
    />} 
   />
  );
}
```

Also removed passing this.props.location and match to this component.